# Alternative for ESP23-WROOM-32D

Tags: arduino, esp32, platform-io

A couple of months ago I designed a board with an ESP32-WROOM-32D (M113DH3200PS3Q0).
Now on the Espressif [product selector page](https://products.espressif.com/#/product-selector) they say it's not recommended for new designs!

Questions:

1. What is the replacement of this module? I guess ESP32-WROOM-32E (M113EH3200PH3Q0) but I didn't find an official document that states that -E version is compatible with -D one
2. Within the same family, there are the 8 MB and 16 MB versions. If I buy them, where should I change the compiler settings (if any!) in Visual Studio Code + PlatformIO?

Comment: compare the datasheets ... it is quire possible that the difference is in something like the antenna